# Number of partitions created in spark rdd

Tags: apache-spark

I have one file called `hello.txt` with 32 bytes in Hadoop file system.
It created 1 data block in HDFS. As I know, ideally it should create 1 partition equal to number of data blocks of file.
But in output I see 2 partitions, See example.

```
-> pyspark --master yarn --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 --name test1

->rdd1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/hello.txt")

->sc.defaultParallelism

o/p:-

2

->rdd1.getNumPartitions()

o/p:-

2

->rdd1.glom().collect()

o/p:-

[['hi hello', 'hello everyone'], ['bye everyone', '']]
```

Can someone explain me how 2 partitions are created in this case instead of 1?

Comment: By the way, you should prefer spark.text to create dataframes rather than rdd

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spark/PySpark creates partitions that are **equal to the number of CPU cores** in the machine. See [Understanding Spark Partitioning](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-partitioning-understanding/)

However, you can explicitly specify the number of partitions to be created.

```
->rdd1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/hello.txt",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the default block size in Hadoop system is 128 MB, so if a file is smaller than 128 MB, it will still take up the whole block, but the remaining space in that block will stay unused.

Your file `hello.txt` is 32 bytes, which is smaller than the default block size, but the Hadoop still allocated one block of 128 MB for the file, and leaving the rest of the block empty.

On the other hand Spark's default parallelism is set to 2, it would split he partition into two smaller partitions for parallel processing. The data in the block will be broken into different partitions, such as one partition is containing `hi hello`, and the other is containing `hello everyone` etc.

And Spark creates partitions based on the Hadoop block size, not based on the actual size of the file data. Therefore, even though `hello.txt` has only one block, Spark will still create two partitions.